# Why my media queries are being ignored?

Tags: css, styles, media

I'm styling an already made website, and any @media queries i put in my css with a max-width below 980px wont even show in Chrome Inspector, the query applies if its for any size larger than 980px normally.

This doesn't work

```
@media screen and (max-width: 979px){
    .custom-home-title-slider {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

this does

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
    .custom-home-title-slider {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both works fine when I test here https://jsfiddle.net/vm36o98y/
Resize the result frame, not the browser window.

Comment: Where in the css are you adding the media query? At the end?

Comment: Im adding it at the end. They do work by themselves, what i'm asking is what should i look for that may be causing my query to be totally ignored. Not even showing up in the Inspector and overriden by other query. Its just not there. But it works as expected with any max-width above 980px.

Comment: Did you check the `<link .../>` element in the HTML to ensure that it isn't including a `media="screen and ..."` attribute?

Comment: I did, and it does include the css file, and the line in the css is there.

Comment: Odd. What happens if you leave out the `screen and`? Have you tried debugging your css, e.g. pasting it into http://csslint.net/ ? Can't see how that could help, given that your 980 query styles work, but couldn't hurt to check

Comment: Its is in fact odd, i tried it in a blank webpage, it works as expected. I forgot to mention this web is built with Angular (not by me), the only thing i can think of is some javascript code that would be overriding styles (it should be visible in the inspector anyway) but i search for that class in the proyect and i dont get any other styles being applied nor any javascript file containing the class.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a relatively old question, but I just came across what I think is the solution. You need to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the document head. Not entirely sure why, but this seems to allow some browsers (Chrome at least) to recognize media queries of width lower than 980.

Comment: You appear to have missed out the code that you believe needs to be added to the document head.